# PYTHON invalid syntax, why is this invalid?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm just beginning to learn python and write now I'm learning how to write files. I keep getting this invalid syntax error where there appears to be no invalid syntax.

```
OUTF = open('ex6.gettysburg.OUT.txt', 'w')
OUTF.write('The text file has '+str(len(getty_toks))+' word tokens\n')
OUTF.write('and '+str(len(getty_freq.keys()))+' unique word types.\n')
OUTF.write('\n')
OUTF.write('The top ten most frequent words are:\n')
for w in sorted(getty_freq, key=getty_freq.get)[:10] :
    OUTF.write(w+"\t"+str(getty_freq[w]+'\n'),
OUTF.write('\nThe top ten longest words are:\n')
OUTF.close()
```

The place where the error supposedly is is on the "OUTF" of OUTF.close() and I've tried retyping it and deleting all the spaces around it or adding a tab above in. I've also tried to see if the error was really mixed spaces and indentation and that's not it. HELP

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Post your traceback here plz

Comment: it just said "invalid syntax", the error was missing a missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing the close bracket `)` at this line:

```
OUTF.write(w+"\t"+str(getty_freq[w]+'\n'),
```

It should be:

```
OUTF.write(w+"\t"+str(getty_freq[w])+'\n')
#----------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got an extra comma there.

```
for w in sorted(getty_freq, key=getty_freq.get)[:10] :
    OUTF.write(w+"\t"+str(getty_freq[w]+'\n'), # right here
```

Remove it and close out your parentheses, and all should be fine, syntax wise.

Comment: Took me over a minute to spot it, so it's hardly surprising the OP was flummoxed. Good eye!

Comment: Good eye.  The syntax error isn't actually the comma, though; it's that the opening parenthesis is never closed. Which you do mention.  The script would actually work even with the comma if the OP closes the parentheses.